# Dynamically name divs in partial for use later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which contains a div, then that div id is currently static. If I use this partial view multiple times, my Javascript class only loads the first div. What is the MVC convention to give these divs a unique ID so this doesn't happen any longer? Would generating a random number work?

Sample code:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var loader = new Class('test');
</script>
```

Ideally I'd like it so every time I render the partial view, an incrementing number is appended to `id="test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there are many ways to tackle this.  It looks like it is important that you be able to reference the additional element in a JS class after loading it.  There are a couple of approaches that come to mind.

1) Add div dynamically via JS ( I am using jquery here to simplify the task ):

add to your class definition:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
  /* you need to add a static method to your class to create
     a unique id.

     Note that this should not be part of your partial view - it
     is only defined once - wherever you have defined your class.
   */
  Class.idNum = 0;
  Class.uniqueId = function() { return 'MyDiv_' + idNum++; };

</script>
```

partial becomes:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >

  // you need to have a 
  var newId = Class.uniqueId();
  var newDiv = jQuery('<div id="' + newId + '" />' );

  // figure out where you need to append it, e.g. to the html body:
  jQuery('body').append( newDiv );

  var loader = new Class( newId );

</script>
```

2) However, a simpler method might be avoiding ids altogether, which is more typical in this kind of dynamic code in my experience.  In this solution, you add all your divs via partials, identify them as a group with a unique class name, and then reference that class name to grab all those divs as a group and iterate over them to create your classes.  Of course, you would have to rewrite your class to refer to these divs by their DOM elements rather than an ID attribute.

Partial becomes:

```
<div class='MyDescriptiveClassName' ></div>
```

Then, after all partials have been added, you would have something like the following javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >

  jQuery('.MyDescriptiveClassName').each( function( index, elem ) {
    // pass in the DOM element for accessing this div.
    var loader = new Class( elem );
  });

</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm boxed into using IDs by the library I'm using, but this works! Thank you!